# Pytest how to check class with list

Tags: python, list, pytest

I new in pytest, problem that I faced is in `assert_called_with` functionalty with dynamic list.

I have class

```
class DbClient:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def save(self, save_dat: list):
        print(f'original-call: {save_dat}')


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.db = DbClient()
        self.my_data: list = []

    def save_data(self):
        if len(self.my_data):
            self.db.save(self.my_data)
        self.my_data.clear()
```

I need to check `save_data` functionality.

This my test function

```
import pytest
from copy import deepcopy
from random import sample
from unittest import mock

@pytest.fixture
@mock.patch("simple.DbClient", new=mock.MagicMock(DbClient))
def main_module():
    return MyClass()  Expected: save([65, 9, 46, 48, 56, 67, 66, 54, 14, 59])
E           Actual: save([])



def test_save_data(main_module):
    input_data = sample(range(1, 100), 10)
    main_module.my_data = deepcopy(input_data)
    main_module.save_data()
    main_module.db.save.assert_called_with(input_data)
```

I facing issue that my test is failing do to `self.my_data.clear()`
the assert returns

```
E           Expected: save([65, 9, 46, 48, 56, 67, 66, 54, 14, 59])
E           Actual: save([])
```

how can i solove the issue with clear()

thank you for any help

i tried to mock `list` without any success, currently i don't know what to-do

Comment: Mock list/inherit from list and make .clear be no-op. I don't do pytest much, but with inheritance: 
```
class MyMockList(list): 
  def clear(self): pass
```
Works just like a list, but .clear() does nothing (edit: comments don't like line breaks - one linebreak and some indent before def and that's all)

Comment: this can be option, but then i can compare if sent list data is correct.

current solution that i'm using is moved ```.clear()``` to out-side of ``save_data``